# Установка нового модуля 1С

Tags: 1с

Здравстуйте .
Есть один модуль FoxyLink , но проблема в том что не могу ни как установить модуль в 1С может даже не понимаю как надо.Не нашел документацию на https://github.com/FoxyLinkIO  .

Я новичок в 1С . Не нашел нормальное видео или статью как установить в сети . Если даже нахожу то они устанавливают через файл (.cf) , но в исходниках нету . Спасибо всем заранее за помощь и внимание

Comment: См. https://infostart.ru/public/317865/

Answer (score 0):

В исходниках есть папка src
Нужно в 1С создать новую базу. Войти в нее в режиме конфигуратора. Далее Конфигурация->Открыть конфигурацию. После этого Конфигурация->Загрузить конфигурацию из файлов... тут нужно указать папку с исходниками /src